# Cмена цвета клетки в tableView

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Как изменить цвет клетки в `tableView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!